# Unable to run haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml in docker

Tags: docker, scala, opencv, docker-compose

I have made a simple **scala** application that uses **OpenCV-4.8.0** that extract face from image via **Haar-Cascade** (`haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`).

The above functionality **working fine** on **local machine**.

Now I'm trying to achieve same functionality through **dockerization**, for this I've followed, following steps.

Here is the `build.sbt`, in which we are creating an Image via sbt-native-packager and then installed OpenCV-4.8.0 via `dockerCommands`.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "human-verification-scala-service"
  )

unmanagedBase := file("opencv4")

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

Docker / packageName := "human-verification-test"

Universal / javaOptions += "-Djava.library.path=/opencv4"

Docker / version := "0.0.1"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8083)

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")

Docker / daemonUserUid := None
Docker / daemonUser := "root"

dockerBaseImage := "amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.18-jdk"

dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  Cmd("RUN", "apk", "add", "--no-cache", "bash make cmake g++ wget unzip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "apk", "add", "--no-cache", "linux-headers"),
  Cmd("RUN", "wget", "-O", "opencv.zip", "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.8.0.zip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "unzip", "opencv.zip && rm opencv.zip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "mkdir", "-p", "build && cd build && cmake ../opencv-4.8.0 && make -j4 && make install")
)

fork := true


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.7.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.5.2",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.11",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.5.2",
  "io.netty" % "netty-transport-native-epoll" % "4.1.99.Final" classifier "linux-x86_64"
)
```

**->** Here in opencv4 directory we have **.jar** and **.so** files of OpenCV-4.8.0 for compiling code, and I'm creating it's docker volume.

**->** OpenCV is working fine in docker as I've tested it in another project as well.

Here is the **code**:

```
object CropImage extends App {

  def getFace(imagePath: String): Mat = {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
    val faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier("/opt/docker/opencv-4.8.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    val image = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath)
    val gray = new Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    val faces = new MatOfRect()
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces)

    if (!faces.empty()) {
      val faceRectArray = faces.toArray
      val faceRect = faceRectArray(0)
      val padding = 220
      val startY = Math.max(0, faceRect.y - padding)
      val endY = Math.min(image.rows(), faceRect.y + faceRect.height + padding)
      val startX = Math.max(0, faceRect.x)
      val endX = Math.min(image.cols(), faceRect.x + faceRect.width)
      new Mat(image, new Rect(new Point(startX, startY), new Point(endX, endY)))
    }
    else {
      new Mat()
    }
  }
   getFace("/src/main/resources/MyImage.png")
}
```

**->** `/opt/docker/opencv-4.8.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` is available after installing OpenCV in docker image.

After doing `docker:publishLocal` in **sbt-shell** it downloaded OpenCV and created the docker **image**.

Then I run image using `docker-compose up`, here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scala-service:
    image: human-verification-test:0.0.1
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources:/src/main/resources
      - ./opencv4:/opencv4
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an **error**:

```
scala-service_1   | # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
scala-service_1   | #
scala-service_1   | #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6a21b60ca9, pid=1, tid=81
scala-service_1   | #
scala-service_1   | # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.21.9.1 (11.0.21+9) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
scala-service_1   | # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.21.9.1 (11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
scala-service_1   | # Problematic frame:
scala-service_1   | # C  [libopencv_java480.so+0x141ca9]  Java_org_opencv_objdetect_CascadeClassifier_CascadeClassifier_11+0xf9
scala-service_1   | #
scala-service_1   | # Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /opt/docker/core.1)
scala-service_1   | #
scala-service_1   | # An error report file with more information is saved as:
scala-service_1   | # /opt/docker/hs_err_pid1.log
humanverificationscalaservice_scala-service_1 exited with code 139
```

here is the `hs_err_pid1.log`:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J+0
j  org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+6
j  blurriness.CheckBlurry$.getFace(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;+11
j  blurriness.CheckBlurry$.isImageBlurry(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/Tuple2;+9
j  faceverification.FaceVerification$.$anonfun$routes$7(Lscala/util/Try;)Lscala/Function1;+222
j  faceverification.FaceVerification$$$Lambda$684.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$1.$anonfun$apply$1(Lscala/Function1;Lscala/Tuple1;)Lscala/Function1;+15
j  akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$1$$Lambda$325.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives.$anonfun$onComplete$3(Lscala/Function1;Lakka/http/scaladsl/server/RequestContext;Lscala/util/Try;)Lscala/concurrent/Future;+9
```

Guide how can I resolve above error, and use `haar-cascade` in `docker container`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading "[Build OpenCV.js {#tutorial_js_setup}](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a8ec6586118c3f8e8f48549a85f2da7a5b78bcc9/doc/js_tutorials/js_setup/js_setup/js_setup.markdown)", you might consider, as an alternative approach, building OpenCV.js using Docker into a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).

Create a Dockerfile that compiles OpenCV.js in the first stage, and then copies the necessary files to a second stage. That approach separates the build environment from the final image, reducing the size and complexity of the final Docker image.

The final stage of the Dockerfile will be based on an image suitable for running your Scala application. If you are using [sbt (Scala Build Tool)](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) for your Scala project, you can start from a Java image, since Scala runs on the JVM.

```
# Stage 1: Build OpenCV.js
FROM emscripten/emsdk:2.0.10 as build-stage

# Clone and build OpenCV.js as before
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git /opencv
WORKDIR /opencv
RUN emcmake python3 ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --build_wasm

# Stage 2: Scala Application
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

# Set Scala and sbt versions
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13.6
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.5.5

# Install Scala and sbt
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y curl && \
  curl -Lo sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Copy the OpenCV.js files from the build stage
COPY --from=build-stage /opencv/build_js/bin /opencv_js

# Copy your Scala project into the image
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Compile the Scala project
RUN sbt compile

# Command to run your application
CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

That Dockerfile first builds OpenCV.js in the first stage and then sets up a Java environment with sbt in the second stage for your Scala project. It copies the compiled OpenCV.js files to the Scala application stage and then compiles your Scala application.

To use this Dockerfile:

- Place the Dockerfile in the root of your Scala project directory.
- Build the Docker image with `docker build -t your-scala-app .`
- Run your Scala application in a Docker container with `docker run -it --rm your-scala-app`.

That would assume your Scala application is correctly configured to use OpenCV.js, perhaps through a JavaScript or WebAssembly runtime environment. Like using [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js/)